# Using Guava's Forwarding Decorators to create specific collections

Tags: java, collections, guava

I have multiple methods that use multiple Collection parameters.

I wanted to make things more specific so I thought using Forwarding Decorator

The first question that comes to mind is:

- Is it an overkill to use the Forwarding Decoartor, am I missing a
     something more simpler , I mean this is very simple thanks to Guava
     but still?

If Forwarding Decorator is the right path then

It seems fine so far, but one thing I am not sure of is how do I get the base collection(ImmutableSet in this case) back?

1. Do I just create a new method (in interface and class) that returns
   "delegate" ?  (If so what would be a good method name?)
2. or is there something more ?

In the following code I am saving a ImmutableSet as setA.

The Code:

Interface:

```
package com.ps.experiment.forwarding;

import java.util.Collection;

public interface ISetA extends Set<String>{}
```

Class:

```
package com.ps.experiment.forwarding;

import com.google.common.collect.ForwardingSet;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;

    public class SetA extends ForwardingSet<String> implements ISetA
    {
        final ImmutableSet<String>  delegate;   // backing list

        @Override
        protected ImmutableSet<String> delegate()
        {
            return this.delegate;
        }

        private SetA(final ImmutableSet<String> strings)
        {
            this.delegate = strings;
        }

        public static ISetA of(final ImmutableSet<String> strings)
        {
            return new SetA(strings);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote is the correct way. If you want to access the back-end collection, simply make `delegate()` `public` instead of `protected`.

Comment: I have a followup question.  Assume that I need 7 such specific interfaces and classes lets assume all ImmutableSet, is there any better option besides copying the code and just changing the class and interface name.  The reason for this is that all 7 things use the same collection type, but I want to make sure that a wrong parameter is not accepted and thus 7 different interfaces and classes.