# Has anyone tried creating Immutable Forwarding Decorators in Guava

Tags: java, collections, guava

I just started experimenting with the Decorators.  One thing I have not seen though is Immutable Forwarding Decorators.  The sample code I am working on is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15140195/532548)

It seems like I can specify an ImmutableSet for the decorator, but there is no compile time warning if the ImmutableSet is a "delegate" of ForwardingSet.

Do I have need to extend the ForwardingSet and create ForwardingImmutableSet and then use that as my decorator?

Has anyone tried this?

Any advice would be helpful.

Using the code link provided above try this:

```
public void test1()
    {
        final ImmutableSet<String> stringsA = ImmutableSet.of("A1", "A2", "A3");

        final ISetA a = SetA.of(stringsA);

        a.add("A0");                // Run-time error
        stringsA.add("A0");     // Compile time warning, Run-time error
    }
```

I just want to see compile time warning for "a.add("A0");"

Of course I have the choice of creating a more restricted interface and I might just start there, but I want to know if I have to do a ForwardingImmutableSet where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

If you want warnings for mutation methods on the immutable collections, you'll have to add them yourself by marking the mutation methods as `@Deprecated` on your forwarding decorator.

In general, the Guava immutable collections are deliberately not subclassable, so that you can't subclass e.g. `ImmutableSet` with an implementation that's not actually immutable.